# Глагол "осчастливить": нужны ли кавычки в переносном (ироническом) значении?

Tags: значение-слов, семантика, глаголы, кавычки, оформление-текста

Скажите, нужно ли (или можно ли, если хочется) брать слово "осчастливить" в кавычки, когда оно употребляется в переносном (ироническом) значении? Такое ощущение, что это факультативно. Или как? Например:

*Тёща (")осчастливила(") зятя своим приездом.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамма.ру" ответила ссылкой на Розенталя (см. [здесь](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.4)). Вероятно, имеется в виду правило кавычек при ироничном значении, так что их ответ, видимо, в том, что кавычки *обязательно* нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Из словаря:
   **ОСЧАСТЛИВИТЬ**, -влю, -вишь; осчастливленный; -лен, -а, -о; св. (кого-что, чем). Сделать счастливым, доставить радость кому-л. О. надолго всю семью. О. своим приходом, появлением, радостным сообщением. Приезд сына осчастливил родителей. <Осчастливливать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.
2. Итак, в словаре переносное (ироническое) значение слова не указано, и тогда в общем случае слово в таком значении заключается **в кавычки**.
3. Но исключения, как мне кажется, возможны. Если из контекста ясно, каковы истинные отношения между людьми, то читатель поймет переносное значение и так. Тогда в авторском варианте орфографии кавычки допускается не ставить.

Интересно, что есть такие выражения, где переносный смысл обозначен **видом конструкции**, например: Нечего сказать, осчастливил!

Также: Один тип, который продал Зимний дворец американскому миллионеру, **осчастливил** своим присутствием наш город. [Т. Тархов. Соло для корнета // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

Здесь явное ироническое значение следует **из контекста**, и кавычек нет.

Comment: Sharon, вы молодец! Но переносное значение, мне кажется, всегда угадывается. И в ваших примерах, и когда кто-то осчасливливает женщину ребёнком, и в других. Хотел спросить, где плюсик автору, но щам я свой тоже лучше отменю...

Comment: Спасибо Артем за поддержку! Я считаю, что смысл часто угадывается  по контексту, но правила есть правила. В таких случаях автор может выбрать форму письма. А вот в совершенно очевидных случаях, когда признаки иронии есть в самом тексте, кавычки не надо ставить.

Comment: Полностью согласен с такой логикой!

Comment: Почему щи не заслуживают плюсика?) Это вкусный суп так-то)))

Comment: Ахахах! Суп заслуживает, особенно если вкусно приготовлен да с говядиной и специями. ;) А если про участника говорить, то я не понимаю его имени и аватарки и из-за этого он остаётся каким-то чужим.

Comment: На аватарке персонаж из аниме "Наруто" по имени Шикамару. Очень умный, но при этом очень ленивый, чтобы что-то делать без пинка. Разделив его имя на 2 части и немного поиграв со словами, получаем Щи, которые я очень люблю, и Комарище — насекомые, которые очень любят уже меня самого... А на аватарке Шикамару как будто закрывает уши от писка комаров. Ну и тех, кто велит не лениться. Как-то так)

Comment: Я поставила плюсик "щам", действительно вопрос интересный. Мы забыли, как бы...ну то есть как бы.

Comment: @ShiKomarishe: спасибо за рассказ! Возвращаю законный плюсик)

Comment: Вот за это благодарю)))

Answer (score 2):

Не просто можно, а нужно, потому что без кавычек слово будет воспринято в прямом смысле.
[Розенталь, § 59.1 п. 5](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=170).